# Reassigning a cells in a stack with the same value to another value

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to reassign cells in a stack with a value of 0 to a value of -9999. The requirement is in a stack of say 3 rasters, if ALL THREE RASTERS have a value of 0 for the same cell, then assign all layers in the stack  a value of -9999 at that pixel location. I have tried to do this with a for loop but i'm thinking my approach 1) is not efficient and 2) it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me understand an efficient way to reassign pixel values with the criteria that ALL CELLS in that pixel location have the same value of 0? I'm sure my approach is not the most efficient.

```
#create some rasters
library(raster)
#create a raster 
myRaster1 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
#assign some random data to the raster
myRaster1[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)
values(myRaster1) <- 0:24
#add some values 0
myRaster1[2:6] <- 0

#create a raster 2
myRaster2 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
#assign some random data to the raster
myRaster2[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)
values(myRaster2) <- 0:24
myRaster2[2:6] <- 0

#create a raster
myRaster3 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
#assign some random data to the raster
myRaster3[]<- 1:ncell(myRaster1)
values(myRaster3) <- 0:24
myRaster3[2:6] <- 0

newStack <- stack(myRaster1,myRaster2,myRaster3)

#calculate rows and columns for loop
rows <- nrow(newStack)
cols <- ncol(newStack)

for (i in rows) {
  for (j in cols){
  if ((newStack[[1]][i,j] == 0) && (newStack[[2]][i,j] == 0) && (newStack[[3]][i,j] == 0)){
  print("this pixel has a value of 0 in all three layers in the stack")
  #assign pixels to -9999
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for any direction and for your time in responding,

Leah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach is to write a function that would operate on a matrix where each row is a cell and each column is a layer. And then use that function in `calc` (in some cases `overlay` is easier).

```
library(raster)
# example data
r1 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
values(r1) <- 1:25
r1[2:6] <- 0
r2 <- r3 <- r1  
s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)

f <- function(x) {
    x[rowSums(x == 0) == 3, ] <- NA
    x
}

z <- calc(s, f)
```

If there are no negative values in s, then function can be simpler

```
f <- function(x) {
    x[rowSums(x) == 0, ] <- NA
    x
}
```

Comment: Thank you @RobertH -- this solution worked perfectly for me and is much more efficient than my other solution new[new==0,] . i tried it on a larger raster.